Save image from CameraX to shared storage
I am trying to understand how to save an image from CameraX to shared storage i.e. so that it is accessible in the default Gallery app. I've been working from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12_iKwGIP64&ab_channel=PhilippLackner) but that does not save the image, it just keeps it temporarily in memory. From what I understand I need a third value in takePicture(), something about building a file, but I'm not understanding how this works (where the image should be saved, path, a new folder or not, permissions etc.). Can you help clarify what I need to change / add in my code below?
private fun takePhoto(
    controller: LifecycleCameraController,
    onPhotoTaken: (Bitmap) -> Unit
) {
    if (!hasRequiredPermissions()) {
        return
    }

// when a photo is taken
controller.takePicture(
    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(applicationContext),
    object : OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)

            // create a matrix
            val matrix = Matrix()

            // if the back camera is being used
            if (controller.cameraSelector == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA) {
                matrix.apply {
                    postScale(1f, 1f)
                }
            } else {
                matrix.apply {
                    // flip the image horizontally
                    postScale(-1f, 1f)
                }
            }

            // create bitmap with changes
            val rotateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                image.toBitmap(),
                0,
                0,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                matrix,
                true
            )
            onPhotoTaken(rotateBitmap)
            image.close()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)
            Log.e("Camera", "Couldn't take photo: ", exception)
        }
    }
)
}


"I'm not understanding how this works (where the image should be saved, path, a new folder or not, permissions etc.)" -- we cannot help you with that without more information. What is your app and the user going to do with the photo after it has been taken and saved to disk? We might be able to make some recommendations given that sort of detail of your hoped-for user experience.

The documentation includes a guide on saving images to the shared storage: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

@CommonsWare "What is your app and the user going to do with the photo after it has been taken and saved to disk?". The app is a basic camera using camerax. At the moment it only stores the image in memory and is lost if the app is restarted. I simply want to get the image out to a file, visible in the default gallery app. I imagine that there is a folder that the gallery app uses so I would guess I need to make a subfolder in that for my app to organse its images. But I'm guessing because I can't find a clear example of anything like this.

"I imagine that there is a folder that the gallery app uses" -- any well-written gallery implementation would query MediaStore. That said, camera apps usually store their images in a subdirectory of DCIM on external storage. "I can't find a clear example of anything like this" -- a GitHub search for LifecycleCameraController turns up many projects that use it.
